# Need help choosing t&p replacement valve

Tags: water-heater

I tried testing the t&p valve on my water heater, and after it kept leaked very badly, I had to shut off the water supply.

[image: valve tag]

I am trying to find a replacement valve, but I don't know how to decipher this.

I'm not sure if this one will work - https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.34-inch-t-p-relief-valve-extended-shank.1000123781.html

I'm in Mississauga, Ontario, Canada, and trying to find something locally asap.  Thanks.

Comment: that one will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same pressure/temperature, greater BTU rating. That part looks good.

But, half the extension, I guess.

Since you are shut down water wise, shut off the heat/power/gas to the water heater and take the old valve with you when shopping.